# What variables are needed for the stochastic frontier production functions to measure if a firm is minimizing costs?

Tags: stochastic

I am trying to help my firm utilize better metrics for future growth. What variables are needed for the stochastic frontier production functions to measure if a firm is minimizing costs or maximizing profits?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming within the definition accepted here.

Comment: Where should I post?